# Imprimir dicionario usando matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Olá,

Tenho um dicionario do tipo:  e gostaria de imprimir um gráfico de linha com a chave k como o x e o v como o y.

tentei uma série de coisas mas continuo recebendo erros:

```
plt.plot(lr.keys(),lr.values())
plt.title('ID modelo:'+str(Index)+' model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.savefig('ID modelo:'+str(Index)+' model accuracy.png')
plt.clf()
```

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_keys'

Comment: Qual a estrutura do dicionário ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em um dicionário, quando você pede somente as `.keys()` ou `.values()` ele dá a resposta junto com um `dict_keys` ou `dict_values`.

É isso que tá acontecendo ai no teu código, o número de tipo `float` está vindo junto com esse `dict` que tá dando esse erro.

***Isso é o que eu acho, observando o que você colocou na pergunta. Se poder colocar mais coisas para que possamos ver melhor.***

Veja,
**exemplo:**

```
dic = {'teste':'teste2'}

>>> print(dic.keys())
>>> dict_keys(['teste']) #Resultado, com dict
>>>
>>> print(dic.values())
>>> dict_values(['teste2']) #Resultado, com dict
```

**Para resolver:**

```
>>> print(list(dic.keys()))
>>> ['teste'] #Resultado, sem dict
>>>
>>> print(list(dic.values()))
>>> ['teste2'] #Resultado, sem dict
```

tente adaptar ao seu código.